# Gitlab-Omnibus Helm chart not launching

Tags: azure, charts, kubernetes, gitlab, kubernetes-helm

I have launched a Kubernetes managed cluster on Azure [AKS].

I am trying to deploy a Gitlab chart via Helm by downloading the zip file and trying to install it.

I use [these charts](https://gitlab.com/charts/charts.gitlab.io) .

I go to this directory `C:\Users\wehappyfew\Documents\Projects\k8s\omnibus\gitlab-omnibus` and I use this command

```
helm install --name gitlab1 --namespace dev .
```

and I get this error

`Error: found in requirements.yaml, but missing in charts/ directory: gitlab-runner`

The gitlab-runner directory exists in the `C:\Users\wehappyfew\Documents\Projects\k8s\omnibus` path.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pull dependencies first.

Follow the following steps:

1. `helm repo add gitlab https://charts.gitlab.io`
2. `helm repo list` to confirm the repo is added
3. `helm dep build`
4. Then run the helm install command

Comment: This may help someone else who'll face this.